# Sort Area Size (KB) - Invalid value for sort area size. The minimum value is: 96 KB

Tags: oracle10g, enterprise, tablespace

When I try to reorganize a tablespace with OEM 10g, I get an error in the 3rd step (options) saying : Invalid value for sort area size. The minimum value is 96 KB. My SGA management is set to AUTO. Why this error on sort size area ? Thanks for your help.

```
workarea_size_policy AUTO
pga_aggregate_target 8192 MB
large_pool_size 16777216 B
sort_area_size  65536
```

Comment: is `sort_area_size` set in in your spFile?

Comment: shouldnt it be in v$parameter thas where i have taken the upper detail from

Comment: thing is if you have it set in your spfile, the defaults and auto-management _probably_ won't kick in. if you want the default behavior, the parameter should not be recorded in the spfile/init.ora (at least, that's the case for some of the parameters, i've never had to tweak that particular one)

Comment: SO do u tweek that particular senario. help please

Answer (score 1):

It is recommeneded to leave this parameter out.
You are using AUTO and defined a very large PGA, let Oracle do it's magic!